# Assert that type is unsigned integer or enum type with maximal size

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to make it possible to write the following to statically assert that a variables type is an unsigned integer with size less than or equal to four bytes.

I started with the following:

```
template<typename T>
using is_uint_le32_t = std::integral_constant<
  bool,
  std::is_integral<T>::value
  && std::is_unsigned<T>::value
  && sizeof(T) <= sizeof(uint32_t)>;
```

So that I can write `static_assert(is_uint_le32_t<T>)`.

However, I would like this alias template to also evalue to `true` when `T` is an enum type whose underlying type satisfies `is_uint_le32_t` and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What is the problem with the obvious solution of making another template that would test that either the type or the underlying type satisfy the condition? What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `std::condtional` to either get an enum type's underlying type or leave any other type alone:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace std_compat {
#if __cplusplus >= 202002L
    using ::std::type_identity;
#else
    template <typename T>
    struct type_identity {
        using type = T;
    };
#endif
}

template <typename T>
using underlying_or_id_t = typename std::conditional<
    std::is_enum<T>::value, std::underlying_type<T>, std_compat::type_identity<T>
    >::type::type;

template<typename T>
using is_uint_le32_no_enum = std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    std::is_integral<T>::value
    && std::is_unsigned<T>::value
    && sizeof(T) <= sizeof(uint32_t)>;

template<typename T>
using is_uint_le32_t = is_uint_le32_no_enum<underlying_or_id_t<T>>;
```

Comment: What's the point of using `type_indentity` here, instead of simply using `T`?

Comment: @super We can't have `underlying_type<T>::type` inside the `conditional`, since that's ill-formed for a non-enum, and `conditional<false, /*ERROR*/, T>` doesn't avoid that error. So the final `::type` needs to be outside the `conditional`, but then in the non-enum case we need that `::type` to "unwrap" something to get back to `T`. (Also, now I'm thinking a partial specialization solution would be simpler...)

Comment: Ah, right. I just now realized you have double `::type::type` outside `conditional` for this purpose. It makes sense now.

Comment: @aschepler: That's exactly what I was struggling with, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might care, I just came up with this possibly simpler solution:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type
is_uint_le32_t()
{ return std::is_unsigned<T>::value && sizeof(T) <= sizeof(uint32_t); }

template<typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type
is_uint_le32_t()
{ return is_uint_le32_t<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>(); }
```

Used like this:

```
static_assert(is_uint_le32_t<T>());
```